# View data not created by the model class appengine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlite

I have data in my database added by non model class method (Say using Sqlite3) running locally 
Is there any way I can view this data or add it to a model schema?
So same database, table created and populated externally, any way to access this data?

Answer (score -1):

there's a variety of sqlite tools that you can use to directly access the database.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

note that this will only work on the dev server, where sqlite is used to emulate the datastore.

The better option is to look at the low level datastore API.  I don't know if there's online documentation, but you can look through the python code in the App Engine SDK, look for `google.appengine.api.datastore`, that has all the basic datastore commands.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do have various means to view the data outside of GAE ie cli or sqlitemanager (for sqlite that is) Django has an import tool for external data which just seems to automatically map fields and tables (I guess i could do that manually?)